# Printing Python output in HTML

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax

I have a Python script (which works and outputs correctly when ran) but I am having trouble posting the output to a HTML page.

No errors are being shown.

I am new to Python.

**PYTHON**

```
import urllib2

def internet_on():
    try:
        response=urllib2.urlopen('http://64.233.160.94',timeout=1)
        return '<img class="right" src="networkon.png" width="32" height="32">'
    except urllib2.URLError as err: pass
    return '<img class="right" src="networkoff.png" width="32" height="32">'

output = internet_on()
print output
```

**HTML/AJAX/JAVASCRIPT**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function wifi() {
        $.ajax ({
            type: "POST",
            urlurl: "file:///home/pi/Desktop/wifi.py",
            data: output,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(responcew){
                $("wifi").html(responcew);
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="topbar">
        <span id="wifi"></span>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I have also tried:

```
function wifi() {
    $.ajax ({
        type: "POST",
        urlurl: "file:///home/pi/Desktop/wifi.py",
        data: output,
        dataType: "html"
    });
    document.getElementById('wifi').innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: What does it do instead of what you want?

Comment: When I run the script `sudo python wifi.py` on my RPi it ouputs correctly in the terminal.

Comment: On the webpage I get no output and no error. @OrangeFlash81

Comment: You only have a success handler so if your code fails it will do so silently. That's not very helpful for troubleshooting. Add an error handler and go from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand why both times you have `urlurl` as the url parameter in your ajax post.

However, even if you corrected that to `url`, it still won't work. You can't post to a file, you have to post to a URL that will be handled by some sort of server process. That could be CGI, but much better to use some kind of (micro-)framework.

Also, you don't seem to have anything in your JS that would actually call the `wifi()` function.

Comment: Ahh typo.  I am wanting to "read" the output from the file not write to it.

Comment: Then you should use GET, not POST. But it still won't work; you have a Python script that needs to be executed by some kind of server, you can't just use a file URL. And you also still don't have anything calling the JS wifi function.